# Corona simulator is vertically aligned

Tags: coronasdk

The emulator is default looks like below image[Default Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdB2J.png)

I want my emulator to look like this
[New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCYWf.png).I have rotated but when I open the project again it shows default image.I want the emulator to be in horizontal orientation.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have code below in your `build.settings`

```
settings =
{
    orientation =
    {
        default = "landscapeLeft",    -- Initial launch orientation
        -- use "landscapeLeft" - Device in the horizontal position with the home button at the left 
        -- or
        -- "landscapeRight" - Device in the horizontal position with the home button at the right
        supported = {"landscapeLeft"},  -- Table of allowed options for auto-orientation 
    },
}
```

More information you can find in documentation in [App Orientation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/#orientation) section .

Answer (score 1):

You can change the orientation of your simulator from portrait to landscape by changing the default value of orientation to either landscapeRight or landscapeLeft in your build.settings file. Or when you create a new project you can click on the sideways radio button under default orientation to change the orientation of emulator to landscape mode.